# will_paginate and packaged_uncompressed.js not found with thin web server

Tags: will-paginate, thin

I recently installed Thin for serving our Rails 2.3.5 app on Heroku. But I'm getting errors like these:

Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /app/tmp/members_packaged_uncompressed.js

NoMethodError: undefined method `will_paginate' for #

These errors also occur locally when I run our app with Thin in production mode. Seems like there needs to be something configured for Thin to work properly with our code? Webrick does not give these errors for our app.

Any advice?